# Why can't I call super method from an in-place event handling function?

Tags: actionscript-3

I have a overriden function in my class, that adds an event handler like so:

```
override public function hide():void {
  ...
  tween.addEventListener(TweenEvent.MOTION_FINISH, function(evt:Event):void {
    ...
    super.hide();
  }, false, 0, true);
}
```

This does not work, Flash tells me: "1006: A super expression can be used only inside class instance methods." (it works if moved to a proper instance method).

So I would like to understand why can't I use call to `super.hide();` from my in-place handler function?

I can refer to any instance variables and methods from there without problems, so I thought that that handler had access to proper context.
Please help me understand this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you can capture the method in a variable that gets stored in the anonymous method's closure. For instance:

```
override public function hide():void {
    ...
    var f:Function=super.hide;
    tween.addEventListener(TweenEvent.MOTION_FINISH, function(evt:Event):void {
        ...
        f();
    }, false, 0, true);
}
```

I can explain further if you are struggling with the concept of closure.

Comment: I guess I should read up on closures to have more than general idea. Thanks :)

Answer (score 6):

it is, because `this` in an anonymous function points to `[object global]` ... have a go, and trace it ...

now an AS3 feature is, that you can access instance members from inside there, but that's a really strange feature ... `this.myProp` will not work, whereas `myProp` will ... this is some dark magic, that automatically creates a closure ... for some reason it works with instance members, but not with `super` ...

IMHO, you should not use anonymous functions anyway, only if it is for prototyping, or as parameters for `Array` methods as `forEach`, `map`, `filter` and the like ...

greetz

back2dos

Comment: Sorry for such long break. I traced some stuff like you said, googled more, read more docs and found no direct answer... Your dark magic theory seems best ;)  
In ASDoc it says in 'super' keyword definition that it may not be used in static context, obviosly, maybe AS treats global as static. Don't know.